# Error cálculo en JS para app POS hecha con PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy haciendo app POS (point of sale) en PHP. Con JS realizo los cálculos como porcentajes, sumas y restas. Tengo una vista principal donde se ingresan, editan y consultan los datos de la empresa como: marca, modelo, potencia, etc.
Hay dos ventanas modales, una que agrega el producto, en este caso una batería (botón azul Agregar Batería), y otra que lo edita, es el icono del lápiz de color amarillo/naranja que se ve a la derecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La parte que me interesa son las columnas: porte y precio total.

Cuando **agrego la batería** en la vista tengo las siguientes clases que luego usaré en JS:

```
  <!-- 7 Ingresar Porte -->

  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="input-group">

      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-percent"></i></span>

      <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg precioPorteBateria" name="nuevoPorteBateria" id="nuevoPorteBateria" min="0" step="any" placeholder="Ingresar porte" required>

   </div>

  </div>


  <!-- 8 Ingresar Precio Total -->

  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="input-group">

      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i></span>

      <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoPrecioTotalBateria" id="nuevoPrecioTotalBateria" min="0" step="any" placeholder="Precio total" readonly>

   </div>

 </div>
```

Ahora pondré el código que tengo en la ventana modal de **editar** los datos que he ingresado anteriormente.

```
  <!-- 7 Editar Porte -->

  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="input-group">

      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-percent"></i></span>

      <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg editarPrecioPorteBateria" name="editarPorteBateria" id="editarPorteBateria" min="0" step="any" required>

    </div>

   </div>

   <!-- 8 Editar Precio Total -->

   <div class="form-group">

    <div class="input-group">

     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i></span>

     <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="editarPrecioTotalBateria" id="editarPrecioTotalBateria" min="0" step="any" required>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Hasta aquí todo bien. El problema cuando en JS quiero editar el porte. Si yo quiero cambiar el porte del producto, primero tengo que restar el antiguo porte del precio total y luego sumarle el nuevo. En JS hago lo siguiente:

```
$(".editarPrecioPorteBateria").change(function(){
    var porte = $(".editarPrecioPorteBateria").val();
    var resta = $(".precioPorteBateria").val(); 
    var porcentaje = Number($("#editarPrecioTotalBateria").val()) - Number(resta) + Number(porte);
    
    $("#editarPrecioTotalBateria").val(porcentaje.toFixed(2));
    $("#editarPrecioTotalBateria").prop("readonly", true);

})
```

.editarPrecioPorteBateria = es el nuevo porte, el editado.

.precioPorteBateria = es el antiguo porte, el que quiero modificar.

#editarPrecioTotalBateria = es el precio final del producto.

El problema que tengo es que no resta el porte antiguo, no reconoce la clase .precioPorteBateria, ya que supongo al no pertenecer a la misma ventana modal no lo encuentra. He probado de todo, no se me ocurre como traer ese dato para poder hacer el cálculo de forma correcta.

Saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Supongo que ambas ventanas modales las generas dinámicamente, y por eso se pierde la referencia de la clase .precioPorteBateria... ¿y porque no recoges el dato de la tabla en su lugar?  ¿o mediante ajax de la base de datos?  Si el modal lo generas a partir del lapiz tendria que ser relativamente sencillo buscar el valor en la propia tabla para su edición. Corrígeme si me equivoco.

Comment: Muy buenas. No puedo corregirte ya que no estoy capacitado para ello. Voy a documentarme con lo que me comentas, que tiene pinta de ir por ahí los tiros. Muchas gracias.

Comment: He conseguido resolver el problema creando otra función: click.function(). Cuando le doy click al box de editarPorte, este automáticamente me lo borre para luego insertar el nuevo porte que con la change.function() , me lo sumará al precio final. Mi nueva lucha es como hacer para que solo se le pueda dar al box una vez, ya que ahora el box editarPorte cada vez que le das resta el porte. Supongo que con un if se puede resolver el tema. Próxima batalla. Muchas gracias @masterguru.